# Why RTL8139 has four Tx descriptors?

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel, ip, driver

I am learning `RTL8139`. I want to know, why do we need exactly 4 Transmit Descriptor Register ? Not less, not more.

I googled for quite a long time and  got a little information from:
  http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/brahma/Resources/beowulf/linux/drivers/rtl8139.html

> On the transmit side four register sets hold the address and size of the packets to be transmitted. While this results in a rather small, fixed-size transmit queue, four entries is adequate for full performance in most environments.

But Why ? What's the meaning of `four entries is adequate for full performance in most environments`. How does it works?

Answer (score 0):

I means network card can be accessed by 4 cores of CPU at same time. Not faster at simple network. But if this computer connected with many clients applicatons has less IO-wait blocks to transmit answer.

Comment: RTL8139 is about designed  in 1997。 I am afraid Realtek's engineer didn't take SMP into consideration.